# Crystal Reports SQL

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

```
IF ({PICT_Picture.Job_Print} = True AND {PROD_Process.Process_Name} in ["LARGE MOULDING","SMALL MOULDING"]) then "YES" else "NO"
```

So basically this is what I want, if a box is ticked `(PICT_Picture.Job_Print)` and if there is either LARGE MOULDING or SMALL MOULDING selected in a drop-down box `(PROD_Process.Process_Name)`, then show YES next to the product in a report otherwise show NO.

At the moment only YES is showing in all of the columns, regardless of having small or large moulding in the field or the box being ticked.

some of the products have images under different process routes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtuhu.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5cYg.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPpOx.jpg

The below images show the fields in question.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/84vyK.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WffWW.jpg

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: shouldn't `{PROD_Process.Process_Name} in [LARGE MOULDING"'"SMALL MOULDING"])` be `{PROD_Process.Process_Name} in ('LARGE MOULDING', 'SMALL MOULDING')` ?

Comment: the comma was a typo, I have since edited it. Do the speech marks make a difference?

Comment: Can you include some sample output that you are getting at the moment?

Comment: I just posted some hyperlinks showing reports and other information. If you require any other information please say as I am currently at work, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In: [image]

Try changing the `Exceptions For Nulls` dropdown to `Defaults For Nulls`.

Also- if you go to `Database`, `Show SQL Query` then copy/paste and execute in management studio/query analyzer and show us the results...

Comment: I tried to get Management Studio/Query Analyser but i don't know where to look. never the less a whizzkid in the office came up with:--------------------


                                                   IF ({PICT_Picture.Job_Print} = TRUE) THEN IF({PICT_Picture.Process_Name}=["SMALL MOULDING","LARGE MOULDING"]) THEN "YES" else
"No" else "No"------------------------------                                           

and it seemed to work.

thanks everyone for your time.